# How to display limited entity in AUI: Autocomplete search suggetion

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

To search user by userId i am using aui: autocomplete, Is there any attribute available to display a limit number of entities in search result as i have a large number of users and while searching it is taking too much of time to load it.

```
 new A.AutoCompleteList(
            {
                allowBrowserAutocomplete: 'true',
                inputNode: '#search_id',
                resultTextLocator: 'userId',
                render: 'true',
                resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
                resultFilters:['phraseMatch'],
                source:userAgList,
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the AutoCompleteList documentation: https://alloyui.com/api/classes/AutoCompleteList.html it seems that there is an attribute for this: maxResults.

Probably using it at the end of your code is enough:

```
 new A.AutoCompleteList(
        {
            allowBrowserAutocomplete: 'true',
            inputNode: '#search_id',
            resultTextLocator: 'userId',
            render: 'true',
            resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
            resultFilters:['phraseMatch'],
            source:userAgList,
            maxResults: 20
        })
```

Anyway this solution may change depending on the version of AlloyUI.